# Remove version from MSBuild publishing command

Tags: msbuild

I'm using the following **msbuild** command line to build a solution but it produces a folder for the project with version appended to it (eg. **myapp_1_0_0_0**). Is there a way to remove the version and just have it **myapp**?

```
msbuild.exe mysln.sln" /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /t:Publish
```

Comment: What is in PublishProfile file? publishUrl property isn't work?

Comment: The `FolderProfile` is builtin from Microsoft. If I specify `PublishUrl`, it gets ignored and published files were put in `bin`. But if I use `PublishDir`, published files get in the right folder but still have the version appended to the folder name. It's a console project if that matters.